# Two parameters zero at the same time

Tags: logistic

How can I test whether two parameters of a logistic regression model are both zero at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perform a likelihood-ratio test between the model including the two parameters & a model excluding both: twice the difference in the log-likelihoods of the models has approximately a chi-squared distribution with degrees of freedom equal to the difference in the number of free parameters (two in this case).

Comment: (+1) Incidentally, this procedure works for linear models generally, not just logistic regression models.

Comment: @user777: As long as one's nested inside the other.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the answer, just wanted to add that this is the realm of Conditional Maximum Likelihood, so the Wald- and LM-tests are available as well. They are actually sometimes preferable if the likelihood function is hard to maximize, because you only have to estimate one model to do these tests. Unrestricted model with Wald and restricted with LM.

Comment: @pkofod: Good point. (For those who don't know: LM test = Lagrange Multiplier test a.k.a Rao's score test.)

Answer (score 1):

I know you said "test" but, since this is related to selecting between two models, you may also be interested on model selection methods rather than hypothesis tests. One of the most popular model selection tools is [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion).  The idea consists of calculating the AIC corresponding to each model and ranking them, selecting the one with the minimum AIC. One of the advantages of this approach is that it is not restricted to nested models.